# Multiple Brown-Forsythe Test and paircomp in same dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, tidy, broom

My experiment has 36 Comparisons, 3 compartments, 21 data points per compartment. Dataset has 2268 obs. in total. The first lines look like this:

```
Comparison  Value   Compartment 
A   -0.715126087    1  
A   -0.481391603    2 
A   0.374693449 1  
A   null    2  
A   0.857450232 1  
A   null    2  
A   -1.608637992    3
A   -1.670859336    3  
A   -1.731618976    3
...    
AJ  -5.84850106 3
```

I run an ANOVA *per comparison* and tested assumptions but had violations in some comparisons. I would like to run a non-parametric Brown-Forsythe F* Test, followed by pairwise comparison. My attempt:

```
if(!require(onewaytests)){install.packages("onewaytests")} # for Brown-Forsythe Test
if(!require(tidyverse)){install.packages("tidyverse")}
if(!require(broom)){install.packages("broom")}

fm3 <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(Comparison) %>% 
  do(multitst = paircomp(bf.test(Value ~ Compartment, data = .)))
fm3 %>% tidy(multitst)
```

Problem: fm3 is not created because it stops running with an error as soon as it hits the first non statistically significant comparison. This is the error I get:

> Error in paircomp.owt(bf.test(Value ~ Compartment,
>   :    Pairwise comparisons could not be performed since difference is
>   not statistically significant (alpha = 0.05).

Wish: To have an output in a table like this:

```
Comparison  term  comparison  estimate  conf.low  conf.high  adj.p.value
1   A   Compartment 1-2 3.360531    2.9495551   3.7715075   2.023126e-11
2   A   Compartment 3-2 3.537098    3.1293925   3.9448041   2.023126e-11
3   A   Compartment 3-1 0.176567    -0.2382312  0.5913652   5.779274e-01
...
108 AJ  Compartment 3-1 4.50731363  2.85507469  6.1595525749    1.954819e-07
```

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could include an ifelse() statement to fill in NA when the comparison is not significant and the results when it is.
     Not familiar with Brown-Forsythe test, but my go-to in such cases is a randomization test.  I guess the decision should be based upon how much information is being lost in using this particular non-parametric test.